# Statistical Analysis for Perception Survey

Tags: survey, stata

### Context:

A sample of people were asked to provide ratings of their impression of [jeepneys](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Jeepney) using a Likert Scale. Age, gender, household income, and so on was also obtained.

**Dangerous:**     strongly agree; agree;  neutral; disagree;  strongly disagree

**Convenient:**    strongly agree; agree;  neutral; disagree;  strongly disagree

**Comfortable:**   strongly agree; agree;  neutral; disagree;  strongly disagree

**Age:**       $\quad<18\quad\quad$   $19-25\quad\quad$   $25\geq\quad$

**Gender:**   male;   female

**Household Income:**   $\quad<3000\quad\quad$  $3001-5000\quad\quad$   $5000\geq\quad$

### Questions:

- What statistical analyses would you recommend?
- How could I implement this in stata?

Comment: I guess you mean "Strongly disagree". You can do all kinds of analysis on it, yet it depends on what type of arguments you want to make.

Answer (score 1):

There are all kinds of analyses you can do. It really depends on what you want to know.

Let me show you, with the example of gender: If you want to know wheter there are gender differences, you can apply a variance test (univariate or multivariate) on the likert scales with the demographic variable as independent factors.

If you just want to see, what scale is distributed how in each gender, then just split the dataset into two.

If you want to know whether there is some correlation between the demographic variables calculate a correlation matrix.

The gist is: You can do anything, but that won't help you and you'll just get lost in the data, if you don't really know what you want to learn. So ask yourself:

- What is my goal?
- What do I need to know to reach my goal?

Then ask again with more specifics.

Comment: I want to measure the overall quality of service using the attributes like safety, convenience, comfort, etc. per age group, income level, occupation.Is it possible to sum the score for each attribute to obtain the overall quality of service? Is it possible to know how important these attributes to people when considering to ride the jeepney? Thanks.

Comment: You could revise your question to clarify this, or set up a new question. Of course you can build a "scale" by combining the three measures. But it's also good to look at the correlations (using a correlation matrix) between the three measures first. This way you can get an idea, whetter people differentiate between those measures, or if they all answer these items in a similar way.

Comment: I used kruskal-wallis test to know if there are gender differences, income differences and so on. Now i have a trouble on how to interpret the results.if the there are no significant differences for each group, is it possible to use the calculated mean rank to see if there is a increasing or decreasing trend?